# why output is displayed as unsigned number

Tags: c++

I'm converting an unsigned array to integer with `sscanf` function, but i'm getting unsigned number??

```
int arr[3];
    unsigned char* tmp = "1223FFFF2222;
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
                sscanf((const char*)tmp, "%4x", &arr[i]);
                tmp += 4;
            }
            std::cout << "X: " << std::dec << arr[1] << " ";
```

OUTPUT  X: 65535 , it should be -1

Comment: It's a positive number with a signed type, not an unsigned number. Signed means "can be negative" not "must be negative". `+` is a sign, too!

Comment: FFFF is -1, how can I get -1 in output instead of 65535

Comment: FFFF is only -1 for a 16-bit signed integer. 16-bit integers are from dinosaur times. I'm pretty sure the only problem here is with your expectation!!

Comment: I guess you're right :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely it's because your integers are more than sixteen bits wide. Two's complement numbers in the range `0x8000-0xffff` will only be negative for 16-bit numbers.

For the more likely case (nowadays) of 32-bit (or even 64-bit) integers, it's just a smallish positive number.

Comment: yes this is the issue finaly, but now i have problem storing 4 hex in short int, I get `Stack around the variable 'arr' was corrupted. `

Comment: @MakhloufGharbi: if you're using `short int`, make sure you change the format specifier to `%hx`. Or, better yet, look into the `uint16_t` type if available.